# Regular Expression Python, space and plus

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get the regular expression of this kind of expressions

```
title="+34 952387749
title="+34 123456789
```

But I've got a problem with the `space` and `+`. As far I got this piece of code but I don't find how to express the space and +

```
^title="+34' space  [0-9]{9}
```

Many thanks for your help !

Comment: Try escaping the plus sign a use a single space `^title="\+34 [0-9]{9}$`

Comment: Try `\+34\s\d{9}`

Comment: Space is a normal char, not any special (unless you use `re.X` or `re.VERBOSE`). The plus sign must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

You need backslashed to specify that you specifically want to search for the +. Your regex would be:

```
\+34 [0-9]{9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Escape the special characters like space and + using .
In RegEx, space is denoted by "\s".
RegEx for your expression would be:

```
\+34\s\d{9}
```

\d is used to denote digit.

Comment: Note that `\s` matches a whitespace character and matches more then a space only.

Comment: True. My bad, should have been more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Try use this regex:

```
 ^title="\+\d{2} \d{9}$
```